# ASP.Net MVC long running tasks in the background?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm working on a web application written in ASP.Net MVC and one action in particular which handles file uploads which are then processed can take roughly 10 minutes to complete, however I would like to return control to the user straight after the file has reached the server ready for processing. I don't need to return anything to the user, just that no errors have occurred.

How should I achieve this, my initial thoughts are async or some kind of queue?

Comment: Async has nothing to do with this. Common misconception: async is only useful when the thread will have periods of waiting (i.e. sitting idle). If you're actually doing work on the thread, async runs as sync, essentially, only with more overhead. Also, async or not, a response cannot be returned until everything is complete. It's not the same as backgrounding.

Comment: @Alex Google results are customized to the user, so the OP may not get the same results as you.  Indeed, in an incognito window it's not in my top 5 results.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure what part of "your google results may be different from other peoples" you didn't understand.

Comment: @Alex in my incognito window, I got different results from you.  This isn't complicated.  "Indeed, in an incognito window it's not in my top 5 results."

Comment: @Alex the problem is the statement "literally the first google result" when his results may be different from yours, as yours are from mine.  What relevance does those rankings have, when I can prove different results are easy to get?

Comment: @Amy Thanks Amy! Google didn't help because I didn't know exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, web applications are uniquely unsuited to handling long running tasks. A web server has a finite amount of threads to work with and it expects to be able to handle requests quickly and efficiently. Anything that takes longer than a second, really, should be offloaded to *a totally different process*, and maybe even an entirely different server.

Essentially what you need to do is have your web application just handle the upload. It'll save it as-is somewhere and then schedule a task to be performed on that file at a later point. It can then just return the response to the user and move on. The task then will be picked up by whatever is handling it and the actually manipulations of the file that need to be performed will be completed at that point. There's many different systems you can use, but probably the most popular in the .NET world is Hangfire. It has a simple client API you can use to schedule tasks and then you can write a console app, Azure function, whatever, to actually perform the task.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the response. This is exactly what I was looking for, I think I fell into the trap of misinterpreting async.